# how to pass values through ajax using grails

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

```
<g:javascript>
 function yes(data){
 var id=$('#id').val(); 
 var pars = 'id=' + id+"&contact_preferences.email="+data;
 $.ajax({
        url: "${createLink(controller: 'userform', action: 'update')}",
        type: 'GET',
        data: pars,           
        success: function(data) {               
              alert("yupee");                
        }
    });
 }
</g:javascript>
```

i really dont know how to pass a value in ajax using type "GET"

Comment: Read the jQuery ajax documentation.

Comment: i know @JamesKleeh .. but  the thing is when i use type GET.. it gives an error.. but when i use Post type its working fine...and the main thing is in grails passing values in different type.. so that controller know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) docs examples how to use data. In your case:

```
var pars = {id:id,contact_preferences.email:data};
```